# Mongoose virtuals in array of subdocument

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Is there a way to "get" the value a document's field in the subdocuments?
book_id is in the main document,how to get the value of it here
'''

```
const ExtraElements_Schema =  new Schema({
    label : {type : String, requires : true},
    page : {type : Number},
    id_resource : {type : Number, required : true},
    description : {type : String}
},{toJSON : {virtuals : true , getters : true}})

ExtraElements_Schema.virtual('path').get(function(){
    const host = global.gConfig.thisServerHost;
    return `${host}/${this.book_id???}/${this.id_resource}`
})

const Extra_Schema =  new Schema({
    label : {type : String, required : true},
    book_id : {type : Number},
    id_extra : {type : Number, required : true},
    extras : [ExtraElements_Schema] 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use virtuals for this too.

```
ExtraElements_Schema.virtual('book', {
  ref: bookTableName,
  localField: 'book_id',
  foreignField: '_id', // Change this if it's not the id that is saved
  justOne: true
});
```

And one thing that bugged me a little I couldn't see the virtuals with console.log I should always use `console.log(model.toJSON())` to see the virtuals